# Zotac ZBOX NANO

Tags: remote-control, hd-video, mkv

Does anybody use Ubuntu on Zotac ZBOX NANO? Is it possible, what is working and what is not? How about playing H.264 1080p video packaged in MKV? Is remote control working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently running Zotac ID84 with 12.04. Under XBMC everything works correctly, all videos (even 1080p) are played and stock remote control is working perfectly. I used this article to setup remote control:

http://youresuchageek.blogspot.fr/2012/06/xbmc-install-and-config-howto-for-linux.html

(see Step 13: Configure Remote Control).

I currently have only one problem with analog audio output under 12.04. When I was running 13.04 on this PC, I had much more problems, especially with power control, sleep mode, etc, but audio was output correctly.